# Set Google Maps Circle Radius to Input Box Value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, button, geometry, inputbox

I am trying to create a tool in google maps that shows the number of markers (which are loaded by a php coded connection to a MySQL database) in a circle, which is placed using a search box. This is working well, thanks to the help I received on this site a few weeks back. Since then I have spent a number of days (on and off) trying to get the radius of the circle to change to the value entered into a user input box that has been placed on the map.

The on click function of the input box is throwing an error saying that the function is undefined. I believe this is due to there being an error in the function named 'updateRadius()' it cannot find the circle variable that I declare earlier in the code.

I was hoping that someone could advise on this. Thank you. Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>

<style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 75%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      /*Styles for Search Box*/
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }

/*Add Styles Radius input box here*/
      .map-control {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        margin: 10px;
        /* Hide the control initially, to prevent it from appearing
           before the map loads. */
        display: none;
      }
      /* Display the control once it is inside the map. */
      #map .map-control { display: block; }

      .selector-control {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>


    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input id="rad" placeholder="Radius" value="200"></input>
    <input id="radius" type="button" value="Click" onclick="updateRadius()"/>

    <script>

var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon57.png';

      /*var customLabel = {
        TE: {
          label: 'T'      }
      };*/

        function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.784032, -73.964436),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeControl: false

        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

                // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

                      // Add a style-selector control to the map.
        //var styleControl = document.getElementById('style-selector-control');
        //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(styleControl);

        var inputBox = document.getElementById('rad');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(inputBox)
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(radius)


  //var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.

  var circle = new google.maps.Circle ({
        map: map,
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng (40.758789, -73.978717),
        radius: 200,
        strokeColor: "#00ff00",
        fillcolor: "red",
        editable: true

  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var place = searchBox.getPlaces()[0];

    if (!place.geometry) return;
    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      circle.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
  });

           function updateRadius(){
        var radi = document.getElementById('rad').value;
        circle.setRadius(parseFloat(radi));
      }




          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('googleMap.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              /*var icon = customLabel[type] || {};*/
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                /*label: icon.label,*/
                icon: image
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }


      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you try to fix the indentation, the nesting is a little hard to see, and I'm pretty sure that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to the nesting of your functions. Basically you have this:

```
<body>
    <input id="radius" onclick="updateRadius()"/>
    <script>
    function initAutocomplete() {
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle ({...});

        updateRadius() {...}
    }
</body>
```

In this scenario, `updateRadius` needs access to `circle` which it has, since they are both in the same scope (the scope of `initAutocomplete`. The problem is that since they are defined inside `initAutocomplete`, they are not visible outside of that function. Your input tries to call `updateRadius`, but it does not have access to the scope of `initAutocomplete` and that's why you get an error. An easy way to fix this would be to just add `updateRadius` to `window` (basically making it a global variable). This is not an ideal solution for larger sites, but probably solves your problem. You can do that by changing this:

```
function updateRadius() {
    ...
}
```

into this:

```
window.updateRadius = function() {
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps, and let me know if you need me to clarify something.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick and helpful response. I’ll give that a go and feedback to you shortly.

Comment: Just tested the recommended code and it works great. Fantastic. That has made my evening, but its also true to say I don't get out much :)